# Duplicate Stack-Layout with diferent parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have this project where I have 3 stack layouts (in the picture I refer each one as "turno"). Each one of then refers to a period of the day.

What I'm trying to do is:

Sometimes There is more then one "turno" per period, so I need to duplicate the stack layout refering to that "turno" (each "turno" have a set of collors and images inside).

If anyone have any ideia of how to do this, using xaml to build the `StackLayout` I appreciate it.

The result:

[image: times of day]

The code:

```
 <StackLayout Padding="10">
    <!--turno 1-->
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="#ebc183"
                 IsVisible="{Binding turno_um}"
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding obs_turno}">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Image Source="turno_um.png"
               WidthRequest="100"
               Margin="5" />
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding dia_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
            <Label Text="{Binding frota_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
            <Label Text="{Binding data_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <!--turno 2-->
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="#f2d061"
                 IsVisible="{Binding turno_dois}"
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding obs_turno}">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Image Source="turno_dois.png"
               WidthRequest="100"
               Margin="5" />
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding dia_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
            <Label Text="{Binding frota_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
            <Label Text="{Binding data_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <!--turno 3-->
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="#438fb2"
                 IsVisible="{Binding turno_tres}"
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding obs_turno}">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Image Source="turno_tres.png"
               WidthRequest="100"
               Margin="5" />
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding dia_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
            <Label Text="{Binding frota_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
            <Label Text="{Binding data_turno}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               MinimumHeightRequest="100"
               FontSize="25" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Do not share the code as images

Comment: if you want to repeat a layout for multiple items, look at Bindable Layouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts

Comment: In my opinion it would be a good idea to create a view/viewmodel for each of your "period of the day". It becomes really easy then to add different parameters to your viewmodel. It also compartmentalizes your business logic.  An architecture that makes sense would be to have one page/view that owns a an observable collection which contains all your "period of the day" viewmodels

Comment: pls post definition of DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) to show a list of "turnos" and use a Selector to select its template according its "turno".

First, create a model and add a Type property:

```
 public class Turno
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    ...
    public TurnoType Type { get; set; }
}
```

In your XAML code:

```
xmlns:selectors="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.App.Helpers"

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <templates:Tuno1ItemTemplate x:Key="Turno1ItemTemplate" />
        <templates:Turno2ItemTemplate x:Key="Turno2ItemTemplate" />
        <templates:Turno3ItemTemplate x:Key="Turno3ItemTemplate" />

        <selectors:TurnoDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TurnoDataTemplateSelector"
                                       Turno1Template="{StaticResource Turno1ItemTemplate}"
                                       Turno2Template="{StaticResource Turno2ItemTemplate}"
                                       Turno3Template="{StaticResource Turno3ItemTemplate}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Turnos}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TurnoDataTemplateSelector}">
</ListView>
```

And create a Selector like this:

```
public class TurnoDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Turno1Template{ get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Turno2Template{ get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Turno2Template{ get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        TurnoType type = ((Turno)item).Type;
        switch (type)
        {
            case TurnoType.One:
                return Turno1Template;

            case TurnoType.Two:
                return Turno2Template;

            case TurnoType.Three:
                return Turno3Template;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your Selector will select a ItemTemplate according its "turno"